# Como inserir jQuery via HTML

Tags: jquery, html

Minha pergunta provavelmente tem uma resposta óbvia, mas eu não consegui achá-la no google.

Tenho um site que usa Wordpress. No site uso um plugin que parou de funcionar (não sei o motivo). Descobri que a causa foi um jQuery que por algum motivo "não estava sendo usado" (não sei a palavra certa para isso).

Constatei que esse era o problema depois que inseri esse código no console do F12 e tudo funcionou:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("h3.symple-toggle-trigger").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Como fazer esse código ser carregado junto com a página sem eu precisar inserir no console?

Comment: Você tem como alterar o HTML? Se tiver é só abrir uma tag `script` e colocar o código dentro dela, após a definição do jQuery.

Comment: Agora que vi que usa o Wordpress... nesse caso terá de ter acesso aos arquivos php do mesmo.

Comment: Talvez esteja tendo conflito entre o `jQuery(function($) {})` e o `$(document).ready(function() {})`, tente remover um ou outro e teste. Se não tiver conflito nenhum, aparentemente o seu código já está sendo executado e o problema é outro.

Comment: A resposta do @MiguelAngelo resolveu meu problema:

Inseri um HTML no footer com o código jQuery entre <script></script> e tudo funcionou. Obrigado :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse código está redundante. Você tem duas opções:

#### 1. Inserir isto no header do HTML:

```
<head>
...
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $("h3.symple-toggle-trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

#### 2. (ou) Inserir  isto logo antes de fechar o body:

```
<body>
...
<script>
$("h3.symple-toggle-trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
    return false;
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Porque inserir a mesma coisa em dois lugares?

Comment: Justamente o que eu precisava! Muito obrigado! No meu caso, inseri apenas no footer, e funcionou.

Comment: @MateusBandeira, repare que eu retirei 2 linhas do código na primeira opção, e 4 na segunda. Nos respectivos contextos, elas eram desnecessárias.

Comment: @LuisHenrique Não é em dois lugares, é em **um ou outro**. Editei pra deixar mais claro.

Comment: @LuisHenrique Não tinha percebido a mudança. Vou alterar o código. Obrigado por avisar.

Comment: Acho que passei despercebido pela frase falando sobre a redundância acima do negrito. Eu sei e vi a diferença entre os dois trechos, porém tinha entendido que você havia dito para inserir ambos.

Comment: @LuisHenrique É que realmente os negritos chamam mais a atenção. Por isso achei melhor incluir um "ou" lá no item 2. Obrigado por avisar!